# Send local Javascript date to server on first access

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there a way to read the user's date when first requesting a page to the server? I'm puzzled on how to sync server time and client time, and maybe sending the client time to the server would be a good solution.

I'm currently doing the inverse, outputting the server time on the page, so JS will read it, but I need to actually read the user's time and then process data on the server based on it.

The only way I can do it until now is loading the page then using an ajax call to send the time.

Comment: Just convert all the times to GMT, and only convert to the local timezone of the user when displaying on the client. No need for sending the client's time to the server (the client's time may be incorrect anyway)

Comment: use ajax technic and http post request by pure javascript. it doesn`t need to jquery or other heavy lib.

Answer (score 2):

From the client side, you can execute an XmlHttpRequest to the server using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var userTime = new Date();
  $.post("path/to/record.php", {"userTime": userTime}, function(data) {
    // do something with data, if necessary...
  });
});
```

On the server, you can log the information however you feel fit:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['userTime'])) {
  $userTime = $_POST['userTime'];
  // do something with it.
}
?>
```